# Identities of commutators

Tags: gr.group-theory, universal-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and set $[x,y]:= x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ as usual and consider it as a binary operation.

> **Question:** Is there a description of the identities that the operation $[.,.]$ satisfies for all groups?

Just to clarify, those identities should not involve ordinary group multiplication, conjugation or inversion (such as the Hall-Witt identity and various other identities) but only commutators and the neutral element.

Of course one has identities of the form $[x,x]=1$ and $[[x,y],[y,x]]=1$ (as pointed out in a comment), but there are also more complicated ones. As an example, one can check the following three-variable identity 
$$[ [[x,y], z],[z,[y,x]]] = [ [[x,y], z],[[x,y],[z,[y,x]]]]$$
and derive one other of similar type. Are all other identities derived from this?

Comment: Since $[y,x]=[x,y]^{-1}$, a simpler relation is $[[x,y],[y,x]]=1$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, right. Maybe one should throw in the inversion as another operation anyway. This does not change the question much, I think.

Comment: Relevant link: http://mathoverflow.net/a/81316/8430

Comment: One can ask whether the set of such identities is finitely generated (under some suitable operations). Namely, let $F$ be the free magma on countably many generators. Let's say that a subset $R$ of $F\times F$ (where we think of an element $(u,v)$ of $F\times F$ as an identity) is coherent if $(u,v)\in R$ implies $(v,u)\in R$, $(wu,wv)\in R$, $(uw,vw)\in R$ for all $w\in F$, and $R$ is stable by substitution (i.e. $(u,v)\in R$ and $f$ implies $(f(u),f(v))\in R$ for every endomorphism $f$ of $R$). (...)

Comment: (...) Observe that if we define $R$ as the set of pairs $(u,v)$ such that $g(u)=g(v)$ for every group $G$ and every homomorphism $F\to (G,[.,.])$, then $R$ is exactly the set of identities you want to describe. It is a coherent subset of $F\times F$ and one question is to describe a nice generating subset of $R$ as a coherent subset and in particular if there is a generating subset.

Comment: @YCor, right, $f$ should be an endomorphism of $F$. Writing "derived from this" would exactly mean that you start with a finite nice set of obvious (or less obvious) identities, close it under the above operations and obtain all identities. Maybe there is some universal algebra consideration that implies that $R$ must be finitely generated in our case -- or maybe some model theoretic argument, since surely the theory of the commutator map can be "interpreted" in the theory of the free groups. But I am not familiar enough this those ideas.

Comment: I don't really expect a general argument, but I added the tag "universal-algebra" because this concerns axioms of binary laws (beyond the associative case). In analogy, if one considers the same question with the law $x*y=xyx^{-1}$ in groups, I think that we get the quandle axioms (I should think twice before saying something too precise).

Comment: @AndreasThom: I doubt it. In general, a fragment of a finitely axiomatized variety (equational theory) obtained by restricting the signature need not be finitely axiomatized.

Comment: An ideal of a free algebra which is stable under substitutions is called a _T-ideal_. I would assume that the notion formulated by @YCor should be called a _T-congruence_ (it is merely a congruence, if we omit the endomorphism-stability property). I do not think that every T-congruence in a free magma is finitely-based; but this does not mean that our concrete one is not;).

Comment: (Btw, one more simple identity which seems not to follow from the mentioned ones is $[x,1]=1$.)

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov. There are even varieties of groups that are not finitely based. (And thanks for the terminology! I added the tag universal-algebra because I expected such useful feedback :)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thanks. Free groups are very special and a lot is known about their first order theory. Especially the study of commutators (maybe not iterated commutators) has played an important role in the work of Zlil Sela.

Comment: @AndreasThom Sure. I'd actually expect the answer here to be finitely based more likely than not. My point is that this is unlikely to follow just from general considerations in universal algebra, as there are similar cases where it fails.

Comment: The following paper may be related to the question:                                    Neumann, Bernhard Hermann. Commutator Laws in Algebraic Systems. Centre for Mathematics and its Applications, School of Mathematical Sciences, Australian National University, 1996.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov you're assuming that the constant 1 is part of the language. If not, anyway these can be rewritten $[[x,y],[y,x]]=[z,z]$ and $[x,[y,y]]=[z,z]$ (so of course 1 will be canonically defined as soon as the structure is nonempty, so assuming 1 is perfectly reasonable).

Comment: There is a paper Clair Miller. The second homology group of a group; relations among commutators. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., 3:588–595, 1952 that shows that all commutator identities in a free group essentially follow from the following ones: $[xy,z]=[x,z]^y[y,z]$, $[x,yz]=[x,z][x,y]^z$, and $[x,x]=1$.

Comment: @Primoz: I am aware of this. But what does it say when you do not allow conjugation?

Comment: @Andreas Thom: I'm assuming you don't want to allow conjugation of commutators, but if you are happy with $[xy,z]=[x^y,z^y][y,z]$ etc, then the same argument like in Miller goes through.

Comment: @Primoz; actually, I am only interested in an answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 2):

The paper [Commutators of flows and fields](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/liebrack.pdf)
contains the following result:

- Let $M$ be a manifold, let
  $\phi^i:\Bbb R\times M\supset U_{\phi^i}\to M$ be smooth mappings for
  $i=1,\dots,k$ where each $U_{\phi^i}$ is an open neighborhood of
  $\{0\}\times M$ in $\Bbb R\times M$, such that each $\phi^i_t$ is a
  diffeomorphism on its domain, $\phi^i_0=Id_M$, and
  $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_0\, \phi^i_t=X_i\in\mathfrak X(M)$. We put
  $[\phi^i_t,\phi^j_t]
      :=(\phi^j_t)^{-1}\circ(\phi^i_t)^{-1}\circ\phi^j_t\circ\phi^i_t.$
  Then for each formal bracket expression $B$ of length $k$ we have
  \begin{align}
  0&= \tfrac{\partial^\ell}{\partial t^\ell}|_0
      B(\phi^1_t,\dots,\phi^k_t)\quad\text{ for }1\le\ell<k,\\
  B(X_1,\dots,X_k)&=\tfrac1{k!} \tfrac{\partial^k}{\partial t^k}|_0
      B(\phi^1_t,\dots,\phi^k_t)\in \mathfrak X(M)
  \end{align}

This suggests that any relation holding for Lie brackets holds also for the group commutator.

#Edit:
I am not sure about the suggestion above. Cor.12 of the paper points in this direction.

A more precise conclusion is: The algebraic structure for the group commutator (alone) has as quotient the algebraic structure of Lie brackets (involving brackets alone). What is the kernel? Is there a kernel?

Comment: It seems like the converse should be true, isn't it? If you differentiate an equality of formal expression of group commutator you obtain the corresponding relation for the Lie algebra. This suggests that for lie groups the relations are exactly the ones coming from Lie Algebras. Am I wrong?

Comment: The formula I know as a translation of the Jacobi identity into group commutators involves conjugates (and says that the product of three triple commutators is 1). I'd be curious if one can do better.

Comment: @YCor: The Jacobi identity involves also sums, which we should not use in answering this question. So my theorem does not apply. The OP could allow a group operation which leads to addition like Trotter's fomula or BCH. Is there a cancellation which leads from reapted BCH applied to group commutators to the formula you mentioned?